# How do I set a custom battery % to turn on Windows Battery Saver?

Tags: windows, windows-10, battery, battery-life, display-settings

You used to be able to set the battery level that triggers Battery Saver to turn on with a high level of granularity in Windows settings, but after recent updates, it can only be set to turn on at "Never, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%, Always."

Users may want to customize this more specifically, e.g. setting the level to 45%, or especially if they have an older computer with a weaker battery, something higher like 70%. There does not appear to be any way to do this via Registry.

Answer (score 1):

Open either a Command Prompt or Powershell in administrator mode, then run:

```
powercfg /setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_ENERGYSAVER ESBATTTHRESHOLD %%
```

(where `%%` is the number between 0 and 100 that you would like to set for the battery level percentage threshold to turn on Battery Saver. 0 corresponds to "Never" and 100 corresponds to "Always").